# T-SQL Procedure not working, issue with varchar to date conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012, date-parsing

When I run this SP, I get:
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PED_SP_PED_Updates, Line 22
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Here is the execution:

```
exec dbo.ped_sp_ped_updates
@CURRENTHICN='111111111A',
@DATERECEIVED = '20140904',
@FIELDTOBECHANGED='FIRST_NAME_MEMBER',
@CURRENTFIELDVALUE = 'MARY',
@NEWFIELDVALUE = 'MARYTEST',
@REQUESTEDBY = 'IPISORS',
@ID=156
```

I am not sure why, I'm casting the varchar back to a date for the comparison.
**Please note**, I have no problem being told a better way to do it, but it would be (I think) more helpful to my learning if I could, at least 'also', get a direct answer as to why my current proc isn't working.  In addition to any helpful ideas as to why it should be done different, better, etc, etc. etc.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PED_SP_PED_Updates]
    @CurrentHicn VARCHAR(500),
    @DateReceived VARCHAR(20),
    @FieldToBeChanged VARCHAR(500),
    @CurrentFieldValue VARCHAR(500),
    @NewFieldValue VARCHAR (500),
    @RequestedBy VARCHAR(10),
    @ID int

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @CurrentDBNote VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @NewNote VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @CountofHicn INT

    SET @NEWNOTE = 'Isaac Pisors | ' + GetDate() + ' | ' 
            + 'Changing field: ' + @FieldToBeChanged + ' from ' + @CurrentFieldValue + ' to ' + @NewFieldValue
            + ', per ' + @RequestedBy + ' request.  Also changing any related DOCS/FAXES records to correspond'

    SET @CurrentDBNote=
        (SELECT NOTES_GENERAL FROM PED_APPLICATIONS WHERE HICN_MEDICARE_NUMBER=@CurrentHicn AND (Cast(ISNULL(DATE_RECEIVED,'1900-01-01') as DATE)=CAST(@DateReceived AS DATE)))

    --NOW ADD THE TWO:
    SET @NewNote = @CurrentDBNote + CHAR(13) + @CurrentDBNote

    --SEE IF THERE IS STILL A MATCHING RECORD
    SET @CountofHicn=
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PED_APPLICATIONS WHERE HICN_MEDICARE_NUMBER=@CurrentHicn AND (CAST(ISNULL(DATE_RECEIVED,'1900-01-01') AS DATE)=CAST(@DateReceived AS DATE)))

    IF @CountofHicn=0  --THERE IS NO LONGER A MATCHING RECORD - INSERT THAT NOTE AND CALL IT A DAY
        BEGIN   
            UPDATE PED_PEDUPDATES SET COMPLETEDON=GetDate(), COMPLETEDBY='SSIS',
            EXCEPTIONNOTE='Could not locate any records where HICN is ' + @CurrentHicn + ' and Date Received is ' + CAST(@DateReceived AS VARCHAR)
            WHERE [ID]=@ID
        END
    ELSE                --GO AHEAD AND DO THE UPDATE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE PED_APPLICATIONS SET @FieldToBeChanged = @NewFieldValue
            WHERE HICN_MEDICARE_NUMBER=@CurrentHicn AND (CAST(ISNULL(DATE_RECEIVED,'1900-01-01') AS DATE)=CAST(@DateReceived AS DATE))
        END

    IF @FieldToBeChanged='HICN_MEDICARE_NUMBER' --THEN WE HAVE TO UPDATE DOCS TABLE, TOO
        BEGIN
            UPDATE PED_DOCS SET HICN_MEDICARE_NUMBER=@NewFieldValue
            WHERE
                (HICN_MEDICARE_NUMBER=@CurrentFieldValue AND (CAST(ISNULL(DATE_RECEIVED,'1900-01-01') AS DATE)=@DateReceived)) or
                (HICN_MEDICARE_NUMBER=@CurrentFieldValue AND DATE_RECEIVED IS NULL)
        END

    IF @FieldToBeChanged='HICN_MEDICARE_NUMBER'     --THEN OUR WHERE CLAUSE-HICN IS THE *NEW* HICN
        BEGIN
            UPDATE PED_APPLICATIONS SET NOTES_GENERAL=@NewNote
            WHERE HICN_MEDICARE_NUMBER=@NewFieldValue AND (CAST(ISNULL(DATE_RECEIVED,'1900-01-01') AS DATE)=CAST(@DateReceived AS DATE))
        END
    ELSE                                            --ELSE OUR WHERE CLAUSE-HICN IS THE *OLD* HICN
        BEGIN
            UPDATE PED_APPLICATIONS SET NOTES_GENERAL=@NewNote
            WHERE HICN_MEDICARE_NUMBER=@CurrentHicn AND (CAST(ISNULL(DATE_RECEIVED,'1900-01-01') AS DATE)=CAST(@DateReceived AS DATE))
        END

    --FINALLY, UPDATE RECORD AS COMPLETE:
    UPDATE PED_PEDUPDATES SET COMPLETEDON=GetDate(),COMPLETEDBY='SSIS' WHERE [ID]=@ID


END


GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Term Fix**

- Instead of `CAST(@DateReceived AS DATE)`, use `CONVERT(date, @DateReceived, 112)`

  The value 112 is the style code for the `yyyymmdd` formated varchar you're using.  See the [cast and convert documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for more details.
- Also, you should verify that all values in the `DATE_RECEIVED` column of your table are in the correct format.  Even one value that is not convertible will cause this error.

**Proper Fix**

- `@DateReceived` should be passed in to the procedure as a `date` instead of a `varchar`.
- The `DATE_RECEIVED` field in your table should be *declared* as a `date` instead of a `varchar`.

In general, avoid treating dates or times as strings in a database when there are native types for that purpose.

Comment: In this answer, I assume you are using Microsoft SQL Server and not some other SQL variant such as MySQL.  If not, please let me know, and tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Whenever I try to tag something, the ultra-slick text editor is too slick for its own good!  I can't type without it converting to something else.  Any time I have a space or hyphen, it usually suggests something I don't want so I was unsure.  Let me try it again and sorry for the confusion.  I will be more careful next time.

Comment: The other day I was reading my million-and-1st article on the web about SQL Server date/date format/etc. articles.  There was a grandiose statement made, something like:  "if you always use YYYYMMDD as the starting point for your string-to-date conversion, you'll never go wrong, regardless of local settings, because that's the ISO standard".
Perhaps I took that statement too much to heart, or.. ?

Comment: ISO format works in many cases, but if you're not careful, you may also be affected by the local machine settings.  The best advice is to NOT deal with string-to-date conversion in SQL.  That's best handled in your application code.

Comment: THAT totally makes sense - thank you.  One more question if I may?  When I run this SQL:
SELECT CAST('20140904' AS DATE)
it seems to be returned as a date type in the results window of SSMS.  This is what made me think that my casting of the passed-in value, ('20140904') couldn't have been an issue.

Comment: Yes, that works in most cases.  Looking through your procedure again, you have way too much casting going on.  Using the proper data types will fix the problem.  But perhaps the value that the error message is complaining about is not the one in `@DateReceived`, but rather one of the values in your table.  Since it's in a where clause, and you're performing functions on the table column, every row in your table will be evaluated.  If even one of them is not in the correct format, you will get this error.  Even more reason to use the correct data type in your table.

Comment: Thanks!!  I found another place where I was concatenating GETDATE() without converting to CHAR, and am now all set.  Appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Could I ask one more question - I have the DATE_RECEIVED in the table as DATETIME, because the time element is sometimes useful. But then, to compare that column to a Date value in (for example, this SP), don't I need to CAST or CONVERT it in order to compare apples to apples?  Like Where Cast(Date_Received as DATE) = @DateReceived?
Even if I go ahead and pass in @DateReceived as Date ?

Comment: The left-side should just be the column name.  Otherwise, you're going to defeat any index you might have.   If you need to work with `datetime`, then use `datetime` everywhere.  If you're storing dates and times, and are querying for all items on a particular date, you'll need to use a range query `WHERE Received >= @thedate AND Received < @thenextdate`  (Use `dateadd` to get the next date).   Also - please try to ask specific distinct questions next time. [Please read this article in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).